# How to get all the descendants of an object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tree, children, ancestry

I'm have models related as follows:

```
GrandParent 
  has_many :kids
  has_many :grand_children, through: :kids
Kid 
  belongs_to :grand_parent
  has_many :grand_kids
GrandKid
  belongs_to :kid
```

I would just like to call .descendants on an object, and get all the objects that belong to its 'lineage'.

I thought that using the ancestry gem would give me the .descendants method I wanted, but it only creates an additional index on a single class, allowing you to get descendants within said class.(great for things like comments & replies, but not useful for my problem) My code is not really necessary to understand the problem, but here it is for those interested: https://gist.github.com/bjlinville1/8425bfe88bc7060209e8

Comment: I would only suggest to shorten your post to the least amount of code required to understand the issue. It is a good question, but the excessive details make the Q lose its meaning. You _may_ want to include your MVC code in a gisthub gist.

Comment: Thanks Hunter, I edited the question for clarity, and I made a gist for it and included simplified MVC.

Comment: Ben, if you use ancestry, you'd only need to create a single model "Person" and the relation within the tree would determine if the instance is a grandparent, kid, grandkid, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're interpreting the ancestry gem incorrectly.
It looks like you expect Region to show up as a child of Country. Is that right?

Ancestry is useful for tree like structures (think folders -> sub folders -> child sub folders -> etc.)

Applying has_ancestry within your Country model would allow you to create countries within countries.  But I don't believe that's what you're looking for.

Regardless, you can set up those relations by setting the "parent_id" attribute for a country when creating/updating it within the controller.  Just set it to the ID of the parent country.
Same for regions if you want a tree structure of regions.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I thought ancestry would do for me. I'm not sure I followed whether or not I could use the parent_ids to accomplish my 'ancestor-descendant' tables, but I got it working right now by just manually coding every view. If you - or anyone else - knows of a nice DRY way to write that table so I can use it on several 'descendants' show pages, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a "region" controller with a "show" action implemented?

Comment: I've updated the original question to include the Regions controller & Region show.html.haml

Comment: This is getting outside the scope of the original question, so you should probably submit a new question for a better answer.  For now, it's possible that what you're looking for can be solved by view partials:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials